# How to get the text inside a paragraph tag .(div/div/p) using Java(for selenium automation)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying get a text from a model using xpath but I end up getting no text , but I could get the tag name.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade custom-modal" id="loginfailure-modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p id="custom-modal-text">We could not find that<br> account. Incorrect email and /<br> or password</p>
                    <button id="custom-modal-btntext" type="button" class="button green-button custom-modal-button" data-dismiss="modal">Please try again</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Trial:

```
String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@id='custom-modal-text']")).getText();
```

I want the text inside the `<p>` tag but am not getting it, but i could get the tag name using get tag name function.

Comment: This is more of an XPath question than a Java one. Please consider changing the tags.

Comment: I have tried your code locally in my system. This is returning text. There may be some other issue. So post your code completely. And also add tag Selenium in it

Comment: if i use gettagname its returning p .. but i could not get the text....  am unable create tag in selenium

Comment: @JoeHalliwell You are right. This is more of a _xpath_ related question. But OP is implementing the _xpath_ through _Selenium_ using the _Java_ bindings. Apparently doesn't relate to _Java_ but OP is using `getText()` where some _Java_ pundits may suggest to use `getAttribute("innerHTML");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To extract the text **We could not find that ... or password** as the element is within a *Modal Dialog* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibilityOfElementLocated* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  String txt = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal.fade.custom-modal#loginfailure-modal div.modal-body>p")).getText();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal fade custom-modal' and @id='loginfailure-modal']//div[@class='modal-body']/p")).getText();
  ```